# Cassandra Data Model for sumed time series data

Tags: cassandra, cql

Time series modeling in C* is easy but what if you would like to add some granularity?

We have a table that looks something like that

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  c_id text,
  purchased_at timestamp,
  revenue_cents integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, purchased_at)
);
```

Now we would like to select all the sales made in the last 365 days and set the time granulation to a week. We could sum it on the frontend, but as far as we would select hundred of thousand of rows, this seems kind of nonperformance, especially if the select speed matters most.

A short example:
In our `sales` table we insert the following sales

```
INSERT INTO sales (c_id, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES (1, '2014-12-15 07:01:00', 200);
INSERT INTO sales (c_id, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES (1, '2014-12-17 08:01:00', 400);
INSERT INTO sales (c_id, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES (1, '2014-12-24 20:01:00', 400);
INSERT INTO sales (c_id, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES (1, '2014-12-16 10:01:00', 600);
```

These can be many thousand sales each day, so if we would like to make a chart over how much revenue got made in the last year, with a query like this:

```
SELECT revenue_cents FROM sales WHERE c_id='1' AND purchased_at > '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
```

We would get back like a million rows, which isn't fast enough. We also don't know the information when each sales was made we just need the information how much got made in on day 225 ( or week 44 or month 6 for example ). So if we would run the query above and want it somehow grouped by month we would get back with 11/12 rows and the revenue_cents are all sumed up. I know C* can't do this right out of the box, but somehow this can be, right?

My question is therefore, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something similar to ["Time Series Pattern 2 Partitioning to limit row size"](http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/), but using a week of the year instead of day of the year for the date, would work for you. Maybe you could use some Cassandra features for granularity in slicing over partition rows described on this page: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use-slice-partition.html. For example:

```
    CREATE TABLE sales (
      c_id text,
      purchased_at timestamp,
      revenue_cents bigint,
      week int,
      PRIMARY KEY ((c_id, week), purchased_at)
    );
```

Using a [composite PRIMARY KEY](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refCompositePk.html) definition will group all the data for a single week.

```
    INSERT INTO sales (c_id, week, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES ('wholesale', 50, '2014-12-15 07:01:00', 1234804938237367);
    INSERT INTO sales (c_id, week, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES ('retail', 50, '2014-12-17 08:01:00', 253480493823736700);
    INSERT INTO sales (c_id, week, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES ('retail', 51, '2014-12-22 20:01:00', 3480493823736700);
    INSERT INTO sales (c_id, week, purchased_at, revenue_cents) VALUES ('retail', 50, '2014-12-16 10:01:00', 250480493823736700);

    SELECT *
    FROM sales
    WHERE c_id='retail'
    AND week=50;

     c_id   | week | purchased_at             | revenue_cents
    --------+------+--------------------------+--------------------
     retail |   50 | 2014-12-16 10:01:00-0800 | 250480493823736700
     retail |   50 | 2014-12-17 08:01:00-0800 | 253480493823736700
```

Comment: Hi catpaws, thanks for your answer, but as far as i'm concerned we would still `SELECT` a thousands of rows instead of just a few for each hour, right?

Comment: Hi Michael Hirn, sorry the answer wasn't sufficient. I guess I don't understand your question and added an example. Hope some discussion leads to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, I updated the question with an example and how the question gets more clear now.

Comment: Well, @catpaws answer is right. For having Cassandra horizontal scalability and huge throughput it is essential to understand how things work here. If you current column family schema doesn't fit your requirements (or queries in this case), then it's likely wrong and has to be redesigned. It seems Cassandra is a right choice in this case, but for current CF schema there's nothing to do unless reducing results on client side. What can be done here is to create another CF's like `sales_by_week`, `sales_by_month`, `sales_by_day` with counters.